# In Google Sheets how do I convert a string containing a date and a time in a sortable date format with a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of cells containing dates, all in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH.mm", I would like to convert them to a format that is then sortable by the SORT() function of GSheets, using a formula and not scripts. I tried DATE but I can only convert the date without the time. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=date(left(A1,4),mid(A1,6,2),mid(A1,9,2))+time(mid(A1,12,2),mid(A1,15,2),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE` too: the sum will return the result.

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

Then, format the cell accordingly so it displays the date instead of the number